# Is there a special name for a 3 foot long drill bit, and where can I buy them?

Tags: tools

I'm looking at the websites for our local hardware stores ([Rona](http://www.rona.ca), [Totem](http://www.totem.ca), [Home Hardware](http://www.homehardware.ca/), [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.ca/)) for a 3 foot long drill bit, but all I'm coming up with is standard bits.

The problem is that it's probably a specialized tool and might even have a special name.

I need a drill bit long enough to punch a hole from my upstairs home theatre room into my basement server room.

Is there a special name for this bit and where might I find such a tool?

Comment: Hahaha, this reminds me of [Spinal Tap](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMVMHNG68m8&feature=related) so much. (Warning: NSFW language)

Comment: You can probably go to a local electrical wholesaler and pick one up.  36, 54, and 72 inches are the norm and you can even get extensions if you need longer.

Comment: Bell-Hanger bit is one standard name, if becoming somewhat out-dated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try searching for "[auger bit](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?keyword=auger+bit&selectedCatgry=SEARCH+ALL&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&Ntpc=1&Ntpr=1)".

Answer (score 9):

[Klein Tools](http://www.kleintools.com/) has some [Flex Auger Bits and Extensions](http://www.service.kleintools.com/Tool/PRD/Category/Flexible%20Drill%20Bits%20DRILLBIT-FLEXDRILL).

Next time you're at the Home Depot check the Electrical section.

Comment: I find these fun to use for some reason.  Most of them have a screw at the tip of the bit to make them self-starting too.

Comment: Ideal makes a good flex bit also. We always called them installer bits.

Answer (score 9):

Try "installer bit"; the flexible ones are particularly nice. I have a 54" one, which is enough to run a line for a light switch into the floor below.

[image]

[image]

There's a hole in the drill bit, which lets you use it as a fish:

[image]

Comment: What is the wire mesh on your pull rod called? I had that at one of my high school jobs, but haven't been able to find it since and don't know its proper name.

Comment: @Kellenjb as far as I can tell, it's just called a "wire mesh cable pull" or "cable grip". A search for that finds a bunch of places where you can buy different sizes with different types of attachments. The one I have came with the installer bit.

Comment: Looks like it works like a chinese finger trap